# Copy curve's tilt from its normal

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves

Let's say I have the geometry of an arm. I would like to take a few continuous edges that go around the wrist and transform them into a curve. Then using an array modifier, create some belts, or cloth wraps etc... The problem that I'm having is that when the curves get more complex, it's really difficult and time consuming to align the tilt correctly. I just need the tilt to match the normal. How can I copy it?

I've found a few solutions in my search that use geometry nodes (e.g. https://blenderartists.org/t/geonodes-align-curve-tilt-to-normal/1476608) but I can't seem to get it work (I'm not sure how to add the curve, direction and tilt to the Group Input). I also found an addon that does this amongst many other things (https://blendermarket.com/products/curvearraypro--magiccurve see the magic curve section), but it seems a lot more than what I need.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: It looks like I am once again the unmentioned original author of part of a paid addon here ...at least the naming *"MagicCurve"*, the date of release and parts of the code suggest it  You can easily solve this with the following answer: [How to correct curve tilt, tangents and normals of a curve?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/271761/). To do this, just capture the normals of the points of your mesh with `Capture Attribute` before converting to a curve, and use this value in combination with the node group shown in the solution. Like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cY8iR.jpg