# Geometry nodes, curve to mesh profile direction

Tags: geometry-nodes

I convert my meshes to curves to give them a profile.
but their direction is different.
how can I fix it?
[image]

[image]

blender 3.6+

[image]

Comment: This has to do something with the generated spline directions. It is obvious that one of them has inverted direction - the square. If you rotate the face in Edit mode along X or Y axis that will resolve the issue. What I suggest is creating the faces always in specific order (clockwise or counter-clockwise). Checking the Spline direction in Geometry Nodes is a bit tricky. I will try and see if a "fool-proof" module can be inserted into the node set up to align the direction of all splines and will post it as an answer.

Comment: ...maybe related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/271761/how-to-correct-curve-tilt-tangents-and-normals-of-a-curve/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Spline direction* controls how the Profile Curve is initially oriented in the **Curve To Mesh** node. The Spline direction is defined by the start and end points of the curve.

There is no, currently, a *built-in* **Node** that tells the Spline direction and not always the ordering of point indices coincide with the direction.

One way to solve setting all Splines to have the same direction is to calculate a **small** change of position along each Spline using the **Factor** parameter (Factor of 0 gives the start of the Spline, and Factor of 1 gives the end of the Spline).

**Note: this works for 2D splines in the XY plane as in your case.**

Using two slightly different Factor values we get two separate positional vectors.
Calculating the **Cross Product** between them give us a third vector perpendicular to the given two vectors and oriented according to their order.
Calculating the **Dot Product** between the third vector and a **Unit Z vector** = (0,0,1) will give a negative or positive number depending on the direction of the two vectors. If they point in the same direction the Dot Product is ***positive***, if they point in opposite direction - ***negative***. The result can be easily converted to **Boolean** value for selection of the splines with the same direction (negative float numbers are always 0-s and positive numbers are 1-s)

Bellow are shown the place of insertion of the custom **Node Group** (*Unify Spline Direction*) and the set up of the Node Group:

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer.

Comment: Hi Pooya. You're welcome.