# geometry nodes, curve to mesh, follow face normal direction

Tags: geometry-nodes

in Geometry nodes, is it possible to use face normal for the direction of **"curve to mesh"**?
(like the left and bottom shape, the right one, doesn't follow the face normal direction)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This task can also be solved with the node group presented [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/271761/):

[image]